# UISegmentedControl width in SplitView

Tags: iphone, ios, orientation, uisplitviewcontroller

I have several UISegmentedControls in different view controllers. On the iPad, when the device changes orientation I realign the segments inside these so they line up with the UITableViews underneath. The problem I'm seeing is that although the resizing mask is set for the UISegmentedControl and without any of my code, it resizes to fill the right width, once I try to change the width of the segments within, the segmented will either not stretch all the way to the end, or they'll be too big and go over.

This only seems to happen when the controls are in a split view.

```
- (void)orientationChanged:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self setHeaderWidths];
}

-(void)setHeaderWidths{
    int totalWidth = self.segSorter.bounds.size.width;
    int areaWidth = 100,
        priceWidth = 100;
    int padding = 35;
    [self.segSorter setWidth:totalWidth -padding- areaWidth-priceWidth forSegmentAtIndex:0];
    [self.segSorter setWidth:areaWidth forSegmentAtIndex:1];
    [self.segSorter setWidth:priceWidth forSegmentAtIndex:2];
}
```

Initially I thought it might be caused by the animation, but even adding a delay so the rotation animation has totally finished has no effect in the width. Are controls within a splitview given a false width or something?

Answer (score 0):

One option you might consider is simply re-creating the control or removing then re-adding the segments.

Without knowing what's going on inside the control, as you change the widths, what if the first one you're resizing (say increasing width) would cause the sum of the widths to exceed the bounds?   Without knowing how that logic is working inside, when I've run across things like this that seem like a fight for a simple change, it's easier to roll a method that just recreates the control as you need it (or removes and re-adds the elements) in the specified sizes.

Comment: The UI is actually loaded from a storyboard, so recreating it programatically seems like a hacky solution.